# firebase gradle issue being added, version 2.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

I keep trying to add the FireBase UI via Gradle in for my app. though for some reason I keep getting errors. I have the correct versions for all my "imports",
I get an "execution failed for task app process debug manifest" error more specifically and have no clue what this means, I'm new to android dev.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.jarvis_main.chatapptest"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.0.0'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

https://gyazo.com/5cef120f2ae2992dc0bf1f3b1e37a5c1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'`

with this

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
```

and if it gives manifest merger error, then Put this at the end of your app module in build.gradle.

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
        if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
            details.useVersion '25.3.0'
        }
    }
}
```

}